# How to compare and show differences on multiple columns in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, compare, multiple-columns

I have a sheet with data in 2 columns, A and B:

```
--A--     --B--
Apple     57
Orange    62
Lime      45
Orange    58
Apple     57
```

What I want is, I need to search column A for duplicates, then if there are any, look for their value in column B. If they are different, I want to color the cell in column A to red, show the other value of that entry in column C, and show a message on how many indifferences there are. Something like this:

```
--A--     --B--   --C--
 Apple     57
 Orange    62       58
 Lime      45
 Orange    58       62
 Apple     57
```

Please help me with this, I know how to compare the value in one column, but then don't know how to search for additional value for them in the other column.

Comment: Please confirm if there is only one possible duplicate in Column A? What have you tried so far? Have you tried **VLOOKUP** plus **IF**?

Comment: There can be multiple instances of "Oranges" in my example, but it can have max only 2 different values in column B (in my example, it can have values of only "62" or "58").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since i am still at learning process it may not be the best solution but it seems it is working

    ```

```vb
' inoG

Sub Solution()

Dim rows As Integer
rows = Range("a1").End(xlDown).Row 'Getting total row number

Dim dt As Variant
dt = Range("a1:c" & rows) 'data into array '

'forward search
For i = 1 To rows
    For j = i + 1 To rows
        If dt(i, 1) = dt(j, 1) And dt(i, 2) <> dt(j, 2) Then
            dt(i, 3) = dt(j, 2)
            GoTo Continue1
        End If
    Next j
Continue1:
Next i


'backward search
For i = rows To 1 Step -1
   For j = i - 1 To 1 Step -1
        If dt(i, 1) = dt(j, 1) And dt(i, 2) <> dt(j, 2) Then
            dt(i, 3) = dt(j, 2)
            GoTo Continue2
        End If
    Next j
Continue2:
Next i

'filling row C and Highlighting
For i = 1 To rows
    If Not IsEmpty(dt(i, 3)) Then
        Cells(i, 3) = dt(i, 3)
        Range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
Next i

'Final Message
Dim totdif As Integer
totdif = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("C1:C1" & rows))
MsgBox totdif

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. However, when I try to use it, an error pops up with: Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class

Comment: I just copy pasted the code it worked on Excel 2013. I can send excel file to you if you want

Comment: If you set rows=12  A1:A12 and B1:B12 cells musn't be blank. first fill cells than run macro. I got same error when i deleted some cells. instead of setting rows =12 you can use      rows = Range("a1").End(xlDown).Row   to dynamically set row number

Comment: Yes, I figured that was the problem, thank you. Yes, it seems to be working, however, sometimes it marks rows even is they are totally identical in both columns (A and B). Also, sometimes it doesn't mark the cells with the red color.

Comment: For solving identical row problem change 
If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Cells(i, 3)) Then
to
If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Cells(i, 3)) And (Cells(i, 2) <> Cells(i, 3)) Then 
SECOND PROBLEM values in column B have to be number otherwise we have to change IsNumber condition something like not blank

Comment: I see that you already edited the code, Thank you again. It seems to be working nearly perfectly, the only small thing is, that if there are 3 identical entries in column A, it sometimes shows you the same entry in column C. Example: In column A there 3 times Apple, and in those rows in column B are 11, 26 and 11, it will write 11 to the column C for the first Apple, even if its column B value is 11 too. For the second and third Apple entry it shows properly though.

Comment: i will try to fix this tomorrow it seems we have to think on this:)

Comment: Ive tried to come up with something, but my knowledge on VBA is limited sadly

Comment: I edited the code if you see any problem let me know to play with this a bit more:)

Comment: Thank you, seems to be working perfectly for me :-)

Comment: but it seems  a bit slow it can be improved by using arrays . if you need improvement or problem let me know. i appreciate new homeworks. it is very helpful at learning:)

Comment: I have a maximum of 500 rows of data in that sheet, so its fine for me :-) Maybe the others in the team will find it slow, and in that case, I will be sure to contact you :-) And again, Thank You for your help.

Comment: Hi again. Just found an error with the code, sometimes it gives this: `Run-Time error 1004. Cannot retrieve property Match class WorksheetFunction.` On this line: `pos = WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("A" & I).Value, Range("A" & I + 1 & ":A" & rows + 1), 0) + I` . Can you please look at it?

Comment: this time i used array instead of range so it is faster. and i rewrite a match function.

Comment: Wow, fantastic, thank you. However, now it gives an error: `Subscript out of range` on this line: `If arr(i, 1) = s Then`

Comment: it means we have one another problem:) how many rows are there in your sheet. it works well here. you can use old code until we solve this problem. the error probably was when a different worksheet was active you run macro. (Run-Time error 1004) . This is our exam week i will try to solve this problem after saturday.

Comment: Sorry, there are 2 columns to check, Column A and B, and put the values to Column C. There are mostly only 100 to 200 rows. If I want to use the old code, which i have saved too, it gives me the Match error.

Comment: facebook/disciplinedstudent  can you send me the excel file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201853/discussion-between-tomas-perlecky-and-disciplined-student).

Answer (score 0):

My following solution used a **helper column** to *rank* the values in `Column B` per item in `Column A` using **COUNTIFS** function. Then I used a pivot table to show the **average** value of each *rank* for each item.

[image: Demo]

Presume you have following **named ranges**:

- **ListItem** being your data in `Column A`;
- **ListValue** being your data in `Column B`.

The formula in Cell `C2` is:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(ListItem,A2,ListValue,">"&B2)+1>1,"2nd Value","1st Value")
```

Change the cell references used to suit your case.

This solution will create an output table laying out all the unique items and then populate the two different values (if there are two) in two consecutive columns next to each item. For comparison purpose I think a pivot table is sufficient and quite efficient.

> P.s. to create a pivot table, you just need to highlight the source table, go to `Insert` tab, and click the **Pivot Table** button to generate a pivot table. Set up the fields in the following way and you will have something similar to my example:

[image: Pivot Fields]

---

**EDIT #2**

If you want to show the second value in `Column C` for each item, here is a formula based approach.

In Cell `C2` enter the following formula and drag it down:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(14,6,AGGREGATE(14,6,ListValue/(ListItem=A2),ROW($Z$1:INDEX($Z:$Z,COUNTIF(ListItem,A2))))/((AGGREGATE(14,6,ListValue/(ListItem=A2),ROW($Z$1:INDEX($Z:$Z,COUNTIF(ListItem,A2))))<>B2)),1),"")
```

[image: Demo2.0]

> The logic is to use `ListValue/(ListItem=A2)` to return a range of values for each item, then use **AGGREGATE** function to *filter* out all the errors, then use
>
> `AGGREGATE(14,6,ListValue/(ListItem=A2),ROW($Z$1:INDEX($Z:$Z,COUNTIF(ListItem,A2))))<>B2`
>
> to further *filter* the range to show the second value (which is different to the first value), then use **AGGREGATE** function again to return that value.

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Comment: Thank you, it does work. However, multiple users will use the same file, and from my experience, someone will screw up the formula, as they did with other files too. Thats why I started to rewrite some of our files to use VBA instead. However, if someone needs a formula for this purpose, this definitely is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with formulas.

If you are concerned about users changing the formula, use a **Table** (and perhaps even protect the formula column, although this would require VBA code to allow expanding the table).  That way the ranges will dynamically adjust to additions and deletions of data, and the users will not need to edit the formula:

With the table renamed `Fruits`, and the columns named as in the screenshot:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(14,6,1/(([@Fruit]=[Fruit])*([@Value]<>[Value]))*[Value],1),"")
```

Use Conditional Formatting to format the cells

[image]

**EDIT:**
I think the table approach would give you a better solution, but for a VBA approach I would use a Dictionary and a collection of the different values associated with the fruits.

Assuming your first column is named "Fruit" (or something you can use in `Find`, or even a known address), you can use the following to create a column of the alternate values for each item.

```
'Add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
'   or use late binding
Option Explicit
Sub diffs()
    Dim myD As Dictionary
    Dim vData As Variant
    Dim rData As Range, C As Range
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet
    Dim I As Long, V As Variant
    Dim colVals As Collection


'Find the table
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet2") 'or wherever
With wsSrc.Cells
    Set C = .Find(what:="Fruit", after:=.Item(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
    If Not C Is Nothing Then
        With wsSrc
            Set rData = .Range(C, .Cells(.Rows.Count, C.Column).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=3)
            vData = rData
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "No data table"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With

'Collect the data into a dictionary
'Max 2 different values per fruit

Set myD = New Dictionary
    myD.CompareMode = TextCompare
    For I = 2 To UBound(vData)
        If Not myD.Exists(vData(I, 1)) Then
            Set colVals = New Collection
            colVals.Add Item:=vData(I, 2), Key:=CStr(vData(I, 2))

            myD.Add Key:=vData(I, 1), Item:=colVals
        Else
            On Error Resume Next 'omit duplicate values
            myD(vData(I, 1)).Add Item:=vData(I, 2), Key:=CStr(vData(I, 2))
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next I

'Populate column 3

For I = 2 To UBound(vData, 1)
    Set colVals = myD(vData(I, 1))
        vData(I, 3) = ""
        If colVals.Count > 1 Then
            For Each V In colVals
                If V <> vData(I, 2) Then vData(I, 3) = V
            Next V
        End If
Next I

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With rData
    .Clear
    .Value = vData
    For I = 2 To UBound(vData)
        If vData(I, 3) <> "" Then
            With rData.Cells(I, 1)
                .Font.Color = vbWhite
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Interior.Color = vbRed
            End With
        End If
    Next I
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, ive tried it, it does work, however, as I've wrote, I need this in VBA. Not just I and my team use the data file, but multiple teams use it for their own purposes and I just cannot convert the data to a Table and add a column just for me and my team. @Disciplined Student was close to what I want, just fix that one bug with duplicates and its done.

Comment: @TomasPerlecky See my Edit and approach. Be sure to read the first comments in the code.